# std::wostream_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, wofstream

Why there are no std::wostream_iterator in C++?

Is there any good reason for this?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> myvec = { L"first", L"second" };

    std::wofstream f("New.txt");
//  std::copy(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), std::wostream_iterator<std::wstring>(f)); // Error
//  std::copy(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring>(f)); // Error
    std::copy(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t>(f)); // Ok
    std::copy(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>>(f)); // Ok
}
```

Comment: Because ostream_iterator does the job?

Comment: wondering why your 2nd `copy` function is error

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Because by default char_type is char

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `std::ostream_iterator` is not `typedef` (and `std::wstring` is typedef on `std::basic_string` with `charT` = `wchar_t`).

```
template <class T, class charT = char, class traits = char_traits<charT> >
class ostream_iterator:
public iterator<output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
```

Second copy operation

```
std::copy(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring>(f));
```

is incorrect, since

```
typedef basic_ostream<charT,traits> ostream_type;
```

so, in this case `ostream_type` is `basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >`

```
ostream_iterator(ostream_type& s);
```

Constructor can receive only this type, but we pass `basic_ofstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >`, it's incorrect.

Comment: still wondering why that 2nd copy function is error since `T` and `charT` parameters can be different